# How to open popup windows using angular js after click on div and pass some object to window

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to know how to open popup window in angularjs with simple animation and background should be blur or dark 
and how to pass object to that new popup window

in html
I have this type div

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-2 rcorners2 " style="height:168px;width:126px;  margin-left: 10px" ng-click="clickevent(app)">
```

app.js I have this:

```
  app.controller('test',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.clickevent=function(app){
      $scope.app=app;
      alert(app.name);
    }
  }]);
```

this app object content different attributes app name description...
those attribute should display in that new popup window with button

how can I do this?

Comment: I recently used [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog) for dialogs and found it really handy.

Comment: ngDialog is horrible and annoying... $modal its a part of ui.bootstrap... I always use that

Answer (score 0):

Wayne suggested ngDialog which is an option but I found it to be really annoying... I simply go with the bootstrap modal or ui.bootstrap $modal... [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) just use $modal...

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use $modal 
   ref: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

> ```
> app.controller('yourController', yourController);
> yourController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal'];
> function yourController($scope, $modal){...}
> ```

then start to use it.

2. use javascript:
   assign an object to window

> ```
>  const pageInfo = {
>              name: 'myPage',
>              url: 'http://myPage...'
>          }
>  window.pageInfo = pageInfo;
>  window.open(pageInfo.url, "_blank");
> ```

then check window.opener on the next page

```
if (window.opener && window.opener !== null) {
    console.log('has initial pageInfo !');
    let pageInfo = window.opener.pageInfo;
} else {
    console.log('No initial pageInfo !');
}
```